# How to define dot startpoint in TOC after renewcommand sections

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec

As I am lazy and do not want to write the same stuff again and again while creating sections which have all the same prefix I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,numbers=noendperiod,toc=sectionentrywithdots]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

    \renewcommand\thesection{Übung \arabic{section}}
    \renewcommand\thesubsection{Aufgabe \arabic{subsection}}
    \renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsection}\alph{subsubsection})}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
%   \newpage
    
    \section{\ }
    
    Text
    
    \subsection{\ }
    
    More text
    
    \subsection{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}
    
    Hardcoded spaces does the job but is counterproductive
    
    \subsubsection{\ }
    
    Final text
    
    
\end{document}
```

It gives me the wanted prefix in the text, but it messes up the starting position of my dots in the table of contents:

[image: MWE output]

So, how do I set a prefix which doesn't mess up my toc-dots? Or i.e.: How do I make sure LaTeX knows where my prefix ends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  numwidth=1em,% minimum width reserved for the entry number
  dynnumwidth% adjustes the width automatically (if more space than numwidth is needed)
]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection}
```

or

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocnumwidth=1em,% minimum width reserved for the entry number
  tocdynnumwidth% adjustes the width automatically (if more space than numwidth is needed)
]{section,subsection,subsubsection}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,numbers=noendperiod,toc=sectionentrywithdots]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[numwidth=1em,dynnumwidth]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynindent]{tocline}{subsubsection}

\renewcommand\thesection{Übung \arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{Aufgabe \arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsection}\alph{subsubsection})}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%\clearpage
\section{\strut}
Text
\subsection{\strut}
More text
\subsection{\strut}
Hardcoded spaces does the job but is counterproductive
\subsubsection{\strut}
Final text
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the following MWE, in which the dotfill still overlaps with the section numbers:

```
\documentclass[12pt,numbers=noendperiod,toc=sectionentrywithdots]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\renewcommand\thesection{Übung \arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{Aufgabe \arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsection}\alph{subsubsection})}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{\hspace{0pt}}
      Text
    \subsection{\hspace{0pt}}
      More text
    \subsection{\hspace{0pt}}
      Hardcoded spaces does the job but is counterproductive
    \subsubsection{\hspace{0pt}}
      Final text
\end{document}
```

Upon compiling the aforementioned code, we end up with some warnings such as:

```
Package tocbasic Warning: number width of section toc entries should be increas
ed!
(tocbasic)                Currently used number width = 46.96692pt,
(tocbasic)                Wanted number separation    = 5.27994pt,
(tocbasic)                Reserved number width       = 19.80011pt on input lin
e 2.

Package tocbasic Warning: number width of subsection toc entries should be incr
eased!
(tocbasic)                Currently used number width = 52.5439pt,
(tocbasic)                Wanted number separation    = 4.69987pt,
(tocbasic)                Reserved number width       = 27.02475pt on input lin
e 3.
```

Following the advice from the warnings, we can use

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=50pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=53pt]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=17pt]{subsubsection}
```

in order to adjust the widths of the section, subsection and subsubsection entries accordingly in order to avoid overlap and excessive white space.

Full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,numbers=noendperiod,toc=sectionentrywithdots]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\renewcommand\thesection{Übung \arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{Aufgabe \arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsection}\alph{subsubsection})}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=47pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=53pt]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=17pt]{subsubsection}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{\hspace{0pt}}
      Text
    \subsection{\hspace{0pt}}
      More text
    \subsection{\hspace{0pt}}
      Hardcoded spaces does the job but is counterproductive
    \subsubsection{\hspace{0pt}}
      Final text
\end{document}
```